# How to use JQuery to highlight a checkobx when it is checked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to highlight the checkboxes checked by a user,
and when they will be un-highlighted when the user unchecked those checkoxes.

But how is it possible to do this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

styling checkbox differs in every browsers... [take a look](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox)

so my suggestion would be:

1. wrap checkbox with span.
2. then give span a padding like 2px or 1px.
3. then when a checkbox is checked, give its span a style like red background.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "highlight", but here goes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkboxID").change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      //checkbox has been checked
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
    }
    else {
      //unchecked
      $(this).css("border", "0");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the jQueryUI Effect() method before, but it has a 'highlight' method.

So I would try something along these lines.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

$('#mycheck:checked').effect('highlight');
```

Comment: this way does not work because the effect happens on the actual checkbox which cannot be seen, at least on my browser Firefox 11.0. What I did was to find the label linked to the checkbox by doing $('label[for=<%= mycheckbox.ClientID %>]').effect('highlight');